# Prove that if $A$ is $R$-projective and $C$ is $S$-injective then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(A,C)$ is $S$-injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module, injective-module

In the situation $(_RA,_RC_S)$, prove that if $A$ is $R$-projective and $C$ is $S$-injective then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(A,C)$ is $S$-injective.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of [Tensor-Hom adjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction). In particular it suffices to assume that $A$ is flat, which is slightly weaker than projective.